# containing type does not implement interface 'IComponentConnector'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image: IComponentConnector is implemented in the generated cs file]

For some reason visual studio **will not** compile the below code.
I am on .NET 6 WPF.
Has there been any breaking changes that doesn't allow me to extend **System.Windows.Window** anymore ?
I am lost for words. The error makes no sense.
I'll post below my xaml and cs for the window:

```xml
<local:ExtendedWindow x:Class="Enciphered.Wpf.Window1"
                      x:TypeArguments="local:RoundedWindowViewModel"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Enciphered.Wpf"
                      mc:Ignorable="d"
                      Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:ExtendedWindow>
```

```cs
namespace Enciphered.Wpf
{
    public partial class Window1 : ExtendedWindow<RoundedWindowViewModel>
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace Enciphered.Wpf
{
    public class ExtendedWindow<TViewModel> : Window 
        where TViewModel: ViewModel
    {
        protected TViewModel? _viewModel;
        public TViewModel? ViewModel
        {
            get => _viewModel;
            set
            {
                if (_viewModel is not null)
                    if (_viewModel.Equals(value))
                        return;
                if (_viewModel is null && value is null)
                    return;
                _viewModel = value;
                DataContext = ViewModel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to remove the following line from the project (`.csproj`) file and then build again:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Comment: Similar solution for me: In the View.xaml.cs file, I had to remove the `#nullable enable` at the top of the file.

Comment: As another solution not disabling nullable functionality in the whole project, I added `#nullable disable` to the code-behind `.xaml.cs` file. However, this sounds like a bug in the XAML code generator, is this tracked somewhere?

Comment: It is now a know/acknowledged issue: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5695  There is also another workaround there

Comment: Worked, but as AlpacaMan stated: not inheriting in Code Behind ( what not is needed, because you can do so on xaml) solves the issue in the way it shoud .

Answer (score 6):

For me, not inheriting from any class in code behind solve the problem.

```
namespace Enciphered.Wpf
{                                
    public partial class Window1 //: ExtendedWindow<RoundedWindowViewModel> // comment out this part solve the problem
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me this is the better solution because, removing nullable will waste up my code warnings!!!